# Javascript 'Dot Dot Dot' While Calculating

Tags: javascript

I have a function to display dot dot dot in a popup window while generating a report. I want to display the text:

**Generating Report.
Generating Report..
Generating Report...**

...repeat, until the report is ready. So far I've only been able to get the three dots in the popup without the other text. Here is my code snippet:

on(link, "click", function(){

```
          var dots = window.setInterval( function() {
            var wait = document.getElementById("reportLink");
            if ( wait.innerHTML.length > 2) 
                wait.innerHTML = "";
            else 
                wait.innerHTML += ".";
            }, 400);

      domAttr.set(dom.byId("reportLink"), "innerHTML", dots);
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
domAttr.set(dom.byId("reportLink"), "innerHTML", "Generating Report" + dots);
```

Comment: Would be useful to see this in a jsFiddle or something similar. It's hard to know how this code is working and what's happening behind the scenes in the convenience `dom` methods and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're passing to `setInterval` is directly manipulating the dom element instead of returning a value (which wouldn't work anyway), so you `"Generating Report" + dots` won't work since `dots` is just a reference to the `setInterval` function. Instead, you need to modify your `setInterval` function using something like this (untested since I'm not sure what JS library/framework you're using):

```
var dots = window.setInterval( function() {
    var wait = document.getElementById("reportLink"),
               msg = "Generating Report",
               msgLen = msg.length;

    // Initialize to msg if blank
    wait.innerHTML = (wait.innerHTML === "") 
        ? msg 
        : wait.innerHTML; 

    if (wait.innerHTML.length >= (msgLen + 2))
        wait.innerHTML = msg;
    else 
        wait.innerHTML += ".";
}, 400);
```

Instead of initializing and testing your message by empty string, this uses the actual message you want to show. I also made the number of dots configurable by variable instead of using a ["magic number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

[EDIT 1]
Make sure you remove this line (and any derivatives):
    domAttr.set(dom.byId("reportLink"), "innerHTML", dots);

The function you're passing to `setInterval` is doing all the work.

[EDIT  2: Fixed the excessive dots on first run by initializing to `msg` if the reportLink element is empty.]

Comment: Hey that works! Thanks. However, when I first click the link it displays "16.........." before it displays "Generating Report"

Comment: *dots* has the value returned by calling *setInterval*, it's not a reference to the function itself.

Comment: OK. I changed dots to setInterval in the domAttr.set line. It displays "function setInterval{}" before "Generating Reports..."

Comment: If you still have this line: `domAttr.set(dom.byId("reportLink"), "innerHTML", dots);` remove it. The function being passed to `setInterval` is doing all the work.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. It's a quibble, but is there a way to remove the underline from the text? It's a hyperlink before it's clicked.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it helped! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted ;) You can use CSS to remove the underline. I would need to see your markup to give an exact answer but something like: `#link_id {text-decoration: none;}` should do it, assuming the link has an id of 'link_id'. Of course, you can use any CSS selector that applies to the link.

Comment: I added another edit to prevent it from having a bunch of dots on first run by initializing `reportLink` element to the value of `msg` if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var dots = window.setInterval( function() {
   var wait = document.getElementById("reportLink");
   if ( wait.innerHTML.length > 19) 
       wait.innerHTML = "";
   else 
       wait.innerHTML += ".";
   }, 400);

var text = "Generating Report" + dots;
domAttr.set(dom.byId("reportLink"), "innerHTML", text);
```

When you check the length you need to include the length of 'Generating report'.

Comment: `dots` is just a reference to `setInterval` and won't return a "dots" string.

Comment: oops, my bad. I missed that

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
var wait = document.getElementById("reportLink");
var loop = 0;
var text = "Generating Report";
window.setInterval( function() {
    if ( loop > 2) {
        wait.innerHTML = text;
        loop = 0
    } else {
        wait.innerHTML += ".";
        loop++
    }
}, 400);
```